# How I can set value from select in PostgreSQL function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I declared some variable in a PostgreSQL function (plpgsql), and I want to set a value from select table. How I can do it correctly?

Function like this:

```
DECLARE
 a NUMERIC(18,6);
 b int;
 c int;
 d NUMERIC(18,6);
 e int;
 f boolean;
BEGIN

SELECT  a = "st"."cl1",
              b = "st"."cl2",
              c = "st"."cl3",
              d = "st"."cl4",
              e ="st"."cl5",
              f ="st"."cl6"

FROM "test"."table" st limit 1;
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    "st"."cl1", "st"."cl2", "st"."cl3", "st"."cl4", "st"."cl5", "st"."cl6"
    into
    a, b, c, d, e, f
from "test"."table" st
limit 1;
```